# Keeping a GUI session on screen

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, display

I installed Ubuntu11.04(ja) desktop edition.

I login to this via ssh from my local pc and use "screen" to keep ssh session running when I disconnect, but, this command is only to kepp cui session.

I want to know how to keep gui session when I disconnect from local PC, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

[VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) does exactly this. You can disconnect from a desktop session and come back to it sometime in the future.

Comment: thank you! I installed vnc4server. Is any configration necessary?

Comment: You probably want to create an `xinitrc` file in your `~/.vnc` directory; it'll be executed when you run the server, and establish your session. It might include the `startkde` command, for example. You'll also want to set a password, so it's not completely unprotected.